# Laravel many to many relations say no method users

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two models which are `User` and `Group` and they have a many-to-many relationship.

**Group.php**

```php
<?php

namespace BOOK_DONATION;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class group extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id','book_id',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [

    ];
    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('BOOK_DONATION\User', 'group_user')->withPivot('last_seen_id');
    }
}
```

User.php

```php
amespace BOOK_DONATION;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use BOOK_DONATION\User;
use BOOK_DONATIOM\Book;
use BOOK_DONATION\group;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email','country','state/provience','city', 'token', 'password','postal_code',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password','verfied', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function Book(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Book');
    }

    public function groups(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('BOOK_DONATION\group', 'group_user')->withPivot('last_seen_id');
    }

}
```

Now I have controller with the following line:

```php
return view('chat.messaging')->with('group',$group->users());
```

What I get is:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::users does not exist.

But as you can see, the `Group` model does have a `users` method, so what is the problem?

Comment: `$group->users()` is a not the correct way to get the users. Change it to `$group->users->get()` to get users of the group.

Comment: @RutvijKothari when i used what you said I get "Property [users] does not exist on this collection instance."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's telling you that `$group` is a `Collection` of group models, not a single instance of a `Group` model. The `Collection` itself does not have a method called `users`.

In your controller, how is `$group` defined? If you're doing a query such as `group::all()`, you'll end up with a `Collection`.

Calling:

```php
Group::with(['users'])->all();
```

will load all the `groups` AND all the `users`. and then you can iterate through each group and have all the `users`.

**Edit:**

As per Mark's comment on his query, he should be changing his get to a first to get a single model as a result.

```php
$group = group::with(['users'])->where('id', '=', $group_id)->first();
```

and the remove the parentheses on the call to the view

```php
return view('chat.messaging')->with('group',$group->users);
```

Comment: $group=group::where('id',$group_id)->get();

Comment: With this query, you are returning a Collection of group models (even if there is only one group, you'll still get a Collection. It looks like you are trying to get a single group judging by the use of group_id, so change your get() call to a first(). Then, as others have suggested, in your view just use $group->users without the parentheses. I will update my answer with this.

Comment: Off topic specifically, but there are a couple of style things you look into to make your life easier. Change the definition of the group class to Group (capital G). This will help you differentiate your model references in your code. Also, your view call is calling "with('group', $group->users)". You'll end up with a view variable called "group" containing only a Collection of users and not the group itself, which will confuse you a lot!. Better to just just pass the group itself, and you can call $group->users in the view.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I see an error:

When you call a relation **with the parentheses** `()` at the end, you will access the relationship itself, this means that you can keep adding query contraints, for example:

```php
// with the following you access all the users of the relationship.
$group->users()->get();
// with the following you access all the users of the relationship with an id=123
$group->users()->where('user_id', 123)->get();
```

Now, when you do it **without the parentheses** `()` at the end, you access the result of the relationship, this means, the elements that exist in that relation.

So, in this case, the `users` of that specific `$group`. This will be an instance of `Collection`, a collection of `User` models, that is what you should return to the `view` in your case:

```php
return view('chat.messaging')->with('group', $group->users);
// or
return view('chat.messaging')->withGroup($group->users);
```

---

Now, if we look at your error message:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::users does not exist.

This is telling you that `$group` doesn't have a `users` method but as we can see in your code it does have one. The problem must be how you are getting the `$group` object, probably you are doing one the following:

```php
$group = App\Group::where('id', 'some_id')->get();
// or
$group = App\Group::all();
```

This will also return a collection of items (`get()` / `all()`), do this instead:

```php
$group = App\Group::where('id', 'some_id')->first();
```

or even better:

```php
$group = App\Group::find('some_id');
```

Those will return an instance of a `Group` model, a single object instead of a collection, that must has the `users` method defined in it.